# Java - generic classes hierarchy and generic methods overloading

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, overloading

I have a (non abstract) generic base `class A<L,M>`, an abstract generic sub `class B<K, L, M> extends A<L,M>` and a (non abstract) `class C extends B<Integer, Integer, Void>` :

```
public class A<L,M> { }

public abstract class B<K, L, M> extends A<L,M> { }

public class C extends B<Integer, Integer, Void> { }
```

I have a utils class that has a few methods, two are relevant here:

```
public static <K, L, M> void doSomething(B<K, L, M> b) {...}
public static <L, M>    void doSomething(A<L, M>    a) {...}
```

To be clear, both methods have the same name.
If I call `doSomething(c);` (where `C c`) it goes as expected to the 1st method.
My issue is with the following code (at another class that uses the utils):

```
private void doSomethingMoreComplex(A a) { // a is actually C
    Utils.doSomething(a);
}
```

So here `a` is actually `C` but it goes to the second method, I am not sure if I made a mistake in the code or this is actually the expected behavior.

Comment: "I have a (non abstract) generic base..." show code, rather than describing it in words.

Comment: "or this is actually the expected behavior." Yes, it's the expected behavior. The compiler chooses which method is run, and it doesn't know that it is a `B` (because you've said it's an `A`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the expected behavior. The runtime type of `a` is inconsequential, as this method resolution is done in compile time. Since `doSomething(B)` cannot be applied to an argument of type `A`, the method is resolved to `doSomething(A)`.

You could handle this yourself by explicitly downcasting `a`:

```
private void doSomethingMoreComplex(A a) { // a is actually C
    if (a instanceof B) {
        Utils.doSomething((B) a);
    } else {
        Utils.doSomething(a);
    }
}
```

... but, well, in a word - yuck.

The more idiomatic way to address this would be to have `doSomething` as a method of `A` and **override** (**not overload**) it in `B`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done, but I might look for another solution (maybe renaming) because it looks odd to me

Comment: I'll have to think about the second option, because the method does not seem to fit into the actual class, so overriding might not be possible.

Comment: Alternatively, you can define the method as `private <T extends A> void doSomethingMoreComplex(T a, Consumer<? super T> consumer)`, and pass in `Utils::doSomething` as the `consumer`.

Answer (score 3):

> or this is actually the expected behavior.

Yes, it's the expected behavior.

The compiler chooses which method is run, and it doesn't know that it is a `B` (because you've said it's an `A`). So it doesn't know if the first overload is safe to invoke, but it knows the second overload is.

Comment: Out of curiosity and maybe because I have forgotten the name: what is this "technique" called that the compiler decides the method call, not the runtime?

Comment: @luk2302 isn't it called "compile time polymorphism"?